# Anyway to detect recent Android OS crash?

Tags: android, crash

Is there anyway to detect if the Android operating system (not the app) crashed and rebooted the phone?

It would need to be for an app to detect when that has occurred within the app itself--so looking at logs as the developer isn't a suitable option.

Edit: I'm already using the receiver to make my app aware when boot completes--but I need to distinguish in that moment if there was an OS crash or if the phone was simply restarted or turned on/off.

Comment: I think its a security breach. So, android won't allow that

Comment: How would knowing that a crash occurred be a security breach?  I get that accessing logs could have private information in it, but I'm not even trying to read logs, just get a boolean value of phone recently crashed or not.  Can't imagine how that is a breach in security--my guess is it's more likely just not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` event:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <receiver
        android:name="CustomReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then in your receiver, do the action you wanted to perform:

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, WordService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

This does not provide if system is crashed or battery drained or simply restarted. Also not sure if you can access Android logs without rooting the device.

Comment: I already do this to restart the app--I need to know if the cause of the restart was a OS crash or not though.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to get **Android OS Crash logs** from apps. Infact if it would be, it would be a security breach.

> Android Applications are **sandboxed**, each app running in its own instance
>   of **Dalvik Virtual Machine** (now Android Runtime).

And the generic android OS doesn't provide any such bridge to let apps collect OS crash data. For that, you will need to build an android from **AOSP**.

Comment: I'm not looking to get logs, just a true/false if the phone crashed.  However it sounds like that isn't supported from what you and everyone else is saying.